# avoid Race condition - BlockingCollection

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I'm using .NET 3.5 and need a slimmed version of a BlockingCollection (that doesn't necessarily need to be strong typed).

I've come up with the following which is more than enough for my needs in terms of features, but I think suffers from a race condition:

```
public class WuaBlockingCollection
{
    private const int TimeoutInterval = 50;
    private readonly Queue _queue = new Queue();
    private readonly AutoResetEvent _event = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private readonly object _queueLock = new object();

    public bool IsAddingComplete { get; private set; }

    public void Add(object item)
    {
        lock (_queueLock)
        {
            if (IsAddingComplete)
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    "The collection has been marked as complete with regards to additions.");

            _queue.Enqueue(item);
        }

        _event.Set();
    }

    public object Take()
    {
        if (!TryTake(out var obj, Timeout.Infinite))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "The collection argument is empty and has been marked as complete with regards to additions.");
        }

        return obj;
    }

    public bool TryTake(out object obj, int timeout)
    {
        var elapsed = 0;
        var startTime = Environment.TickCount;
        obj = null;

        lock (_queueLock)
        {
            if (IsAddingComplete && _queue.Count == 0) return false;
        }

        do
        {
            var waitTime = timeout - elapsed;

            if (waitTime > TimeoutInterval || timeout == Timeout.Infinite)
            {
                waitTime = TimeoutInterval;
            }

            if (_event.WaitOne(waitTime))
            {
                break;
            }
        } while (timeout == Timeout.Infinite || (elapsed = unchecked(Environment.TickCount - startTime)) < timeout);

        if (timeout != Timeout.Infinite && elapsed >= timeout) return false;

        var isQueueEmpty = false;

        lock (_queueLock)
        {
            if (_queue.Count == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }

            obj = _queue.Dequeue();

            if (_queue.Count > 0)
            {
                isQueueEmpty = true;
            }
        }

        if (!isQueueEmpty)
        {
            _event.Set();
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void CompleteAdding()
    {
        lock (_queueLock)
        {
            IsAddingComplete = true;
        }

        _event.Set();
    }
}
```

More specifically, in the `TryTake()` method around the `if (!isQueueEmpty)` part.

Basically in between `isQueueEmpty` being set and something being done with it's value another thread might do something that affects `_queue.Count`.

Theoretically only the `Add()` or `CompleteAdding()` should be able to do this (because multiple threads running `TryTake()` would be stuck at either the `lock()` or the `_event.WaitOne()`) but I'm not sure if this is either something to worry about nor how to actually fix it without putting the `_event.Set()` inside the `lock` itself which I believe might have adverse effects.

If the answer is to put the `_event.Set()` inside the `lock`, please clarify why this would not impact on the event and whether any further modifications are required.

Comment: `if (_queue.Count > 0)
            {
                isQueueEmpty = true;
            }` seems odd.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want the `_event.Set()` inside the `lock`?

Comment: @mjwills In short, I don't know how putting `_event.Set()` inside a lock might affect other `_event` related activities that are not inside a lock. (like the `_event.WaitOne()` that _cannot_ be inside a lock)

Comment: You might want to use a Semaphore rather than an AutoResetEvent. It makes synchronization a bit simpler in that case

Comment: @KevinGosse can you provide some code to see what it'd look like with a semaphore?